# How to connect Postgresql Docker Container with another Docker Container

Tags: postgresql, docker, networking, docker-compose

I want to connect `mysoft` docker container to `postgresql` docker container.
But i have some errors:

```
ERROR: for mysoft_db_1  Cannot start service db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint mysoft_db_1 (XXX): 
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint mysoft_db_1 (XXX): 
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use
```

here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysoft:
    image: mysoft/mysoft:1.2.3
    ports:
      - "80:8080"  
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://mysoft:PASSWORD@db/mysoft?sslmode=disable
  db:
    image: postgresql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=mysoft
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
      - POSTGRES_DB=mysoft
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

I want use another, already running docker pg server to connect new soft, also one pg docker server, for more projects
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should add [links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#links) to the definition of `mysoft` service in `docker-compose.yml`. Then your `db` service will be accessible from `mysoft` container.

After that your service definition will look like this.

```
mysoft:
  image: mysoft/mysoft:1.2.3
  ports:
    - "80:8080"  
  environment:
    - DATABASE_URL=postgres://mysoft:PASSWORD@db/mysoft?sslmode=disable
  links:
    - db
```

Now about error of binding. Probably, you receive it, because you have a local postgresql running on port 5432 or you already have a running docker container with 5432 port mapped to local machine.

```
ports:
  - 5432:5432
```

It is used for mapping ports to your local machine. And if you don't need to access container's db from it, just remove it.

> I want use another, already running docker pg server to connect new
>   soft, also one pg docker server, for more projects Is it possible?

Yes, it's possible. Use [external_links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#external_links).

If you choose this option:

1. Remove the `db` service and `links` in `mysoft` service definition from your `docker-compose.yml`
2. Add `external_links` with correct container name to `mysoft` service definition.
3. Update host and port in `DATABASE_URL` according to the container name and postgresql port in it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check of you already have a local postgres running on port 5432? If you do you can not do the ports 5432:5432 but have to expose the inner port to an other outer port e.g. 5555:5432

at least if you are using native docker (running on localhost)...